# Error with running bower init on interactive mode in git bash

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, git-bash

$ bower init --config.interactive
bower error         Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

> Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
>       at Interface.rl._getCursorPos (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\readline2\index.js:51:51)
>       at ScreenManager.render (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\lib\utils\screen-manager.js:19:27)
>       at Prompt.render (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\input.js:75:15)
>       at Prompt._run (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\input.js:49:8)
>       at Prompt.run (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\base.js:57:8)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\prompt.js:84:12)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\run-async\index.js:15:21)
>       at AnonymousObservable.__subscribe (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\lib\utils\utils.js:16:7)
>       at AnonymousObservable.tryCatcher (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\rx-lite\rx.lite.js:63:31)
>       at setDisposable (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\rx-lite\rx.lite.js:5741:44)
>
> Console trace: Error
>       at StandardRenderer.error (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:82:37)
>       at Logger. (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower:110:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at Logger.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at Logger.emit (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
>       at C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\commands\index.js:48:20
>       at _rejected (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:844:24)
>       at C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:870:30
>       at Promise.when (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:1122:31)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\dolap_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:788:41)

System info:
Bower version: 1.6.5
Node version: 5.0.0
OS: Windows_NT 10.0.10586 x64

Comment: is there a solution to this or do i just have to use the nodes command prompt ?

Comment: It seems it's an open issue on gthub https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/272